# Esther stay married to achashveiros

Tags: megillat-esther, intermarriage, esther--the-woman

Why did Esther stay married to achashveirosh and have a child with him after the Jewish people were saved?

Comment: ...probably because royal marriages back then were usually terminated by death.

Comment: We are dealing with  a fool who kills his wife because of his friend and turns around and kills his friend because of his wife. We easily assume that just like he saved a people in order to save his wife, he can kill a people in order to kill his wife. So she probably didn't want to anger him.

Comment: For the same reason that she married him in the beginning.

Comment: But wasn't it asur for her to be with him?

Comment: How do we know she got pregnant after the story?